# App crashea en el portrait, null pointer exception en un Texview

Tags: java, android

En un proyecto para Udacity, mi app crashea al llegar a esta linea en mi ui/ArticleDetailFragment class
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La app solo crashe en portrait mode, un null pointer exception salta.
como veis el reviewer me deja un hint pero no se como solucionar el problema.

Edit1: (Mas hints)

Currently, the app crashes with the following error on my end when I enter the Detail screen:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface)' on a null object reference
at com.example.xyzreader.ui.ArticleDetailFragment.bindViews(ArticleDetailFragment.java:133)
```

It looks like there's a view which is only available in landscape (articleTitleLand), so if you reference it in portrait, it will be null since it will not be there.

You should fix this issue so that the app avoids crashing in any orientation.

Mi source code: 
https://github.com/AhmedHamdan54/xyz-reader

RESULTO: El problema era que pedia una font que no habia aun añadido al proyecto

Comment: podrias mostrar el xml de ArticleDetailFragment y donde inicializas el textview?

Comment: Ya lo sulcione pero gracias igual

Comment: RESULTO: El problema era que pedia una font que no habia aun añadido al proyecto